# Firebase functions:config:set silently discarding values?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

Just tried this:

```
firebase functions:config:set  firebase.webapikey="XXXXX"

Error: Cannot set to reserved namespace firebase
```

Error is clear. So I tried this:

```
firebase functions:config:set firebaseapis.web="XXXX"
✔  Functions config updated.

Please deploy your functions for the change to take effect by running firebase deploy --only functions
```

Good, no errors. However:

```
carlos@carlos-linux-dev:~/firestore_experiments$ firebase functions:config:get |grep firebase
carlos@carlos-linux-dev:~/firestore_experiments$
```

So that key wasn't actually stored. However if change it to something else:

```
dev:~/firestore_experiments$firebase functions:config:set pithole.web="XXXX"
✔  Functions config updated.

Please deploy your functions for the change to take effect by running firebase deploy --only functions

carlos@carlos-linux-dev:~/firestore_experiments$ firebase functions:config:get |grep pithole
"pithole": {
```

I couldn't find any reference in the documentation about this, seems like a bug... is this actually intended behavior?

And more to the point, is the Web API available automatically to a Firebase project oo is it something that indeed needs to be copy/pasted from the console?

Comment: *"Please deploy your functions for the change to take effect by running firebase deploy --only functions"* – did you do this?

Answer (score 4):

There is an internal bug that prevents keeps config param names starting with the string "firebase" from working correctly, as you had in your second sample that doesn't work. (firebaseapi.web still starts with "firebase").  Start it with any other 8 characters, and you should be OK.

Comment: I understand, but shouldn't I get an error instead of a success message?

Comment: Yes, that's what makes it a bug.

Comment: Apologies, I thought I had read something else. Thanks. Moving on.

Answer (score 0):

> And more to the point, is the Web API available automatically to a Firebase project or is it something that indeed needs to be copy/pasted from the console?

I've been looking for a way to achieve this and have so far had no success.

There is an environment variable available to cloud functions at `process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG` but this does not contain the API key, only the following properties:

```
{
  "projectId":"[project-name]",
  "databaseURL":"https://[project-name].firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket":"[project-name].appspot.com",
  "locationId":"europe-west"
}
```